# How to disable button in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I have an onclick code on my image to disable the button on my form that look like this

```
<img alt="" src="images/search-icon.png" width="16" height="16" style="display: inline;height:16px;cursor:pointer; width: 16px;" onclick="DisableButton('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>');" />
```

And then on my javascript I have a code like this

```
function DisableButton(bSave) {
document.getElementById(bSave).attributes("Enabled", false);
}
```

the problem is it is not working, everytime i click on the image nothing happens. Is there an error on my code? Please help me on this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no attributes in JavaScript and there is no Enabled property in HTML.

Comment: Use document.getElementById("idofyourbutton").disabled=true;

Comment: That's not keyboard accessible. To fix it, wrap the `img` in a `button`, move the `onclick` to the button and change the alt text to `alt="search"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'disabled'

`document.getElementById(bSave).disabled = true;`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_disabled.asp

Clearing up the disable vs disabled ambiguity.

Comment: Adding with example could be better

Answer (score 0):

Here's code :

```
 document.getElementById(bSave).disabled = true;
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
```

Comment: I've tried your code but it is still not working. is ".disable" right?

Comment: There's no error, nothing happens when i click the image.

Comment: Do you know how to brower debugger like developer tools

Answer (score 0):

Please use this it will work
  In your script :

```
document.getElementById(bSave).disabled = true;
```

if you are using jquery then

```
 $("#"bSave).prop("disabled",true);
```

Comment: Then ? Check your answer your code will not work because it is not disable it is disabled